# How does GetMetricStatistics break the time interval for data points?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

With the following code, I intend to get the `CPUUtilization` for the last one hour. What I get is a set of data-points separated by a time interval of `5 minutes`. Why is this?

```
       $dimensions = array(
            array('Name' => 'InstanceId', 'Value' => 'i-4dxxxd95'),
        );

        $stats = $cloudWatchClient->getMetricStatistics(array(
                'Namespace'  => 'AWS/EC2',
                'MetricName' => 'CPUUtilization',
                'Dimensions' => $dimensions,
                'StartTime'  => strtotime('-1 hour'),
                'EndTime'    => strtotime('now'),
                'Period'     => 60,
                'Statistics' => array('Maximum', 'Minimum'),
        ));
```

As per the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.CloudWatch.CloudWatchClient.html#_getMetricStatistics):

```
Amazon CloudWatch aggregates data points based on the length of the period that you specify. 
For example, if you request statistics with a one-minute granularity, Amazon
CloudWatch aggregates data points with time stamps that fall within the
same one-minute period. In such a case, the data points queried 
can greatly outnumber the data points returned.
```

So, I should get all the time stamps within the one minute duration. Isn't it?

Comment: CPU Utilization is only recorded at 5 minute intervals, so you can't get more frequent details for that particular metric

Comment: @MarkBaker What is the use of `Period 60` here?

Comment: I can't answer why the value of 60 in this specific case; some metrics are available to the minute, when a period of 60 would be perfectly appropriate; or you could set Period 4 to get the metric less frequently

Comment: @MarkBaker If I make the start time to `strtotime('-2 days')` how does it count the number of data points to return?

Comment: I'm assuming that it will work out the interval between StartTime and EndTime, and divide by 60, giving intervals of 48 minutes..... then find all the datapoints that fall within each block of 48 minutes, aggregating them together to calculate the value to return (in your case, getting the max and min values)

Comment: @MarkBaker Alright. So if the start time is `0` and end time is `180` and period is `60`, it would find all the data points in the interval of `180/60` (i.e 3) minutes and return the maximum and minimum values.

Comment: That's my interpretation of how it works, yes

Comment: @MarkBaker But according to the documentation `Amazon CloudWatch aggregates data points based on the length of the period that you specify. For example, if you request statistics with a one-minute granularity, Amazon CloudWatch aggregates data points with time stamps that fall within the same one-minute period. `  That would mean, in the time frame (0 - 180 minutes), the API would return 180 results (period was 60 seconds) and calculate the `min` and `max` based upon that.

Comment: With your 180/60 period, the period is 3 minutes, and if metrics are read every minute then the call will aggregate all data for the first 3 minutes, (3 readings) and return the max and min values of those 3; then aggregate for the second block of 3 minutes, etc

Comment: @MarkBaker I understand your point. With start time as `strtotime('-180 minutes')` and end time as `now`, the API returns `35` data points when I expect it to be `180/5` which is `36`.